# SSE Stream save to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

I have a SSE stream and I need to save the results to a Mysql table. I can stream the data from the SSE endpoint in the browser and save to Mysql. The issue is I need a php script to run every 10 minutes in the command line and store the result. The script I am using is below, it only works in the browser - I assume because its javascript.

```
var source = new EventSource("https://sseAPIUrl.com");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
        var posData = event.data;

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                data:{
                    streamData:posData
                },
                type: "post",
                url: "saveSSEFeed.php",
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: presumably the SSE endpoint ( `sseapiurl.com` ) is not under your control?

Comment: That is correct, its a third party API. I want to do a call and get the data and then store the data in a database.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try it's working.

if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
  var source = new EventSource("server.php");
  source.onmessage = function(event) {
    var rest=event.data;
    //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: 'serverdata.php',
            type: 'post',
            data:{data:rest},
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });

})
  };
}
```

Comment: if you want to show it on the browser you can fetch it from the database.